# Set password for the docx, ppt, xlsx file

Tags: encryption, apache-poi, powerpoint, docx, docx4j

How to set password for the docx,ppt,xlsx file in Java?
What are APIs available for this?
I was exploring docx4java. 
Any examples / options are welcome.

Comment: If you mean encrypting a docx document, you could have a look at this POST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501894/what-algorithm-does-microsoft-office-2010-use-for-encryption

Answer (score 0):

```
 DocRaptor
```

**API**

Creating documents using DocRaptor is extremely simple. All you have to do is make a POST request with some parameters!

**Authentication**

Authentication is done through the use of your API key, which can be found on your account dashboard. You can use the api key in one of two ways: either as the value of the query parameter "user_credentials", or as the username for basic http auth. You can see examples of both of these methods in our coding examples.

[REFER](http://docraptor.com/documentation#xls_styles_intro)

Comment: I need to set password for the docx,ppt,xlsx in my application. basically i need to write a java component to set the password and integrate it with my j2ee application.

Answer (score 0):

At work we used the [JOffice / JWord](http://www.independentsoft.com/JWord) api to create docx/pptx files and extract text. I am pretty sure you can use JWord to protect docx files with password.

good luck.